# How to see the sqlite tables while debugging in MAUI?

Tags: maui

Is there a library to see the tables while debugging?

I´m using Visual Studio 2022 with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 7.0.12 on OS Windows 10

For example, on Android I used ObjectBox Admin Web App
https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser

[image]

Comment: on iOS simulator you can access the files in the filesystem.  On a device or Android you would have to extract the files to the desktop

Comment: @Jason Could you explain to me the procedure to extract the sqlite db, or some link? Thank you so much.

Comment: use `adb` to extract files from Android.  Its extensively documented.  On iOS it can be done with the device window in XCode

Comment: Since you say you used that library, most likely you have AndroidStudio already. Use the device explorer.